# RangeError (index)

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I am getting data using APIs but because images are not available now, so I am using List of my own image just for practice and the other data is from the API.

```
  List<String> images = [
    'assets/images/foundationnew.png',
    'assets/images/foundationtwo.png',
    'assets/images/foundationthree.png',
    'assets/images/fondationpowder.png',
    'assets/images/powderfoundation.png',
    'assets/images/foundationnew.png',
    'assets/images/foundationtwo.png',
    'assets/images/foundationthree.png',
    'assets/images/fondationpowder.png',
  ];
```

```
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: productServices.foundationList(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return SpinKitCircle(
                          color: AppColor.secondColor,
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Column(
                          children: [
                            MainProductScreen(
                                image: "assets/images/mainfoundationpage.jpg",
                                productType: ""),
                            Expanded(
                              child: GridView.builder(
                                itemCount: widget.images.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
```

But I am getting rangeError though my list range is from 0:8 and I am still getting this error.

> RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 3

So I don't know,why I am getting this error.

How can I resolve this range issue.

Comment: Part of code that cause that is missing... and by instance, why is not `itemCount: snapshot.data.length`

Answer (score 0):

widget.images.length is more than 3 and you are trying to get the item of images with index that is more than the items

in this case you should check the list that you are trying to get the value from inside the Column make sure its the same list(widget.images)